# Adding columns per referance of id in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, crosstab

I have searched the answer to this question, but no luck so far.

I this table i want to query from:

```
mainId     secondaryId
----------------------
01000        02000
01000        02001
01000        02002
01001        02003
01001        02004
01002        02005
```

I want my query to return this:

```
mainId     secondaryId_01     secondaryId_02     secondaryId_03
---------------------------------------------------------------
01000        02000               02001               02002
01001        02003               02004                     
01002        02005
```

How can i do this, the most simple way?

Comment: what is your dbms

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` & do aggregation :

```
select mainid,
       max(case when seq = 1 then secondaryId end) as secondaryId_01,
       max(case when seq = 2 then secondaryId end) as secondaryId_02,
       max(case when seq = 3 then secondaryId end) as secondaryId_03   
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by mainid order by secondaryId) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by mainid;
```

Comment: Thanks for this awsome example. This works and solves this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PIVOT  - it'll work in sql server

```
with cte as
(
select mainId,secondaryId,row_number() over(partition by mainid order by secondaryid) as rn
from tablename
)

select mainid, pv* from
cte pivot(max(secondaryid) for rn in ([1],[2],[3]))
```

or You can try using conditional aggregation

```
select mainid, max(case when rn=1 then secondaryid) as secondaryid_01,
max(case when rn=2 then secondaryid) as secondaryid_02,
max(case when rn=3 then secondaryid) as secondaryid_03
from cte 
group by mainid
```